# Husbands and wives

Tags: combinatorics

There are 5 married couples wanting to cross a river by a boat. The boat can carry at most 3 persons at a time and of course cannot cross the river by itself with no one on board.

The problem is that all the husbands are extremely jealous. So no woman can be in the presence of another man unless her husband is also present. Even a woman alone in a boat at a bank which has other men on that shore without her husband is not permissible.

In other words at no point of time can women outnumber men on bank or shore because that would mean some woman is husband-less!

It is assumed that everyone knows how to row and all persons on the boat disembark and board at the same time.

Given the constraints provided, what is the minimum number of one-way trips needed to transport these 10 people at the opposite bank? Please indicate also the arrangements.

I found 11 one-way trips. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do math problems have to be formulated in such sexist terms?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: In which way is it sexist? Note that it doesn't claim that those husbands have reason to be jealous, just that they are.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The older version of this problem that I learned long ago involved missionaries and cannibals. Is that better?

Comment: @Sal.Cognato what about my solution?

Answer (score -1):

I've found this

1. $W_1 \to H_1$
2. $W_1,W_2 \to H_1,H_2$
3. $W_1,W_2,W_3 \to H_1,H_3$
4. $W_1,H_1,W_2,H_2 \to W_3,H_3$
5. $W_2,H_2,H_3,H_4,H_5 \to H_1,W_1$
6. $W_2,H_2,W_3,H_3,W_4,H_4 \to H_5,W_5$
7. $W_1,H_1,W_2,H_2,W_3,H_3,W_4,H_4 \to H_5$
8. $W_1,H_1,W_2,H_2,W_3,H_3,W_4,H_4,W_5,H_5$

Comment: Can you explain a little further? How does D2 appear together with D1 and M2 with M1? Same also for the rest of the moves.

Comment: @Sal.Cognato If I'm not wrong the condition is "so no woman can be in the presence of another man unless her husband is also present" which doesn't mean that 2 women can't stay toghether

Comment: @Sal.Cognato Note also that the LHS represent persons on the other side of the rifer the arrow $\to$ represents people going away by the boat. I didn't indicate the starting river for clearness.

Comment: Correct but I don't understand what you mean by your symbols: For example, what does $D_1 \to M_1$ mean? That the two persons (man and woman) cross the river together? Then how does the boat come back to the opposite  bank?

Comment: @Sal.Cognato Yes it represent the first trip $D_1$ and $M_1$ come togheter and $D_1$ rest on the other side and $M_1$ come back i the boat, then $M_1,M_2$ and $D_2$ arrive for the second trip and so on.

Comment: @Sal.Cognato I've edited the symbols with W for wife and H for husband, I can add a description for each trip to be more clear